# Notification when new value is added to the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm using array(object) in my application to represent a set of values. I need to notify the user if the new value is added to the collection and also if any value is deleted, but i don't know how get notification when value is added to that collection. I searched a lot but i can't get any solution to get notification when new value is added or deleted in the array

My code is like this

```
var arr=[1,2,3,4,5];

$("#add").click(function(){
arr.push(6);
});


$("#delete").click(function(){
arr.pop(2);
});
```

How i get the notification when values added or deleted?. Is there any events to get notification like [collectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.collectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: after push, you could trigger an event.

Comment: @krishan or better yet, put all that into a functon

Answer (score 0):

```
function alert_user(value,action) {
    alert("Value "+value+" was just "+action+".");
}

$("#add").click(function(){
    arr.push(6);
    alert_user(6,'added');
});


$("#delete").click(function(){
    arr.pop(2);
    alert_user(2,'removed')
});
```